# How to get Google PR by HTTP request in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, http, google-apps-script, seo, pagerank

I'm working on Spreadsheet that contains list of sites and rates them. Part of rating algorithm is Google PageRank. Now I don't know how to create a request to get PR, rather I don't know on which URL send request. Can you help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my [repository hosted at GitHub](http://github.com/florianbussmann/pagerank) for a suitable script in PHP.
Below is an example for Google Apps Script in combination with the mentioned script on GitHub.

```
function getPageRank() {
  // Generate a log, then email it to the person who ran the script.
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://cdn.florianbussmann.de/github/pagerank/script.php");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = 'Fetched PageRank';
  var body = Logger.getLog();
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

Feel free to ask further questions.